# PyInstaller not working because of Win32 module

Tags: python, winapi, module, pyinstaller

Today I installed PyInstaller using `pip install pyinstaller`, and the first time I try to use it I get an error.

This is the end of the Traceback:

```
    import pywintypes
  File "c:\users\david\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\win32\lib\pywintypes.py", line 124, in <module>
    __import_pywin32_system_module__("pywintypes", globals())
  File "c:\users\david\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\win32\lib\pywintypes.py", line 64, in __import_pywin32_system_module__
    import _win32sysloader
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

In `win32` folder there is a file `_win32sysloader.pyd` and in `win32/lib` the file `pywintypes.py`.

I tried to add `__init__.py` file to `wind32/lib` containing `from win32 import _win32sysloader`, but it's not help.

Comment: This sounds similar: https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/37

Comment: I have embedded python...

Comment: And even if I copy all of `pyd` files in `win32` to `win32/lib`, still same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error.
`import _win32sysloader
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found`
installing Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package fixed the error
https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1840